# "Code" explanation drop down highlight is very hard to see when asking a question

Tags: bug, design

It's very hard to see what help block I'm in.

I suggest making the highlighting color darker, or is this a setting on my display or Chrome browser?

[image: hard to see what block I"m in]

Comment: Huh... I never realized there *was* any highlighting. :o